# Laravel: Upload picture to public/images - wrong file name

Tags: php, laravel, image, file-upload, laravel-8

i'm trying to save an uploaded picture in the public/images directory.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg|max:5048'
    ]);
    $newImageName = uniqid() . '-' . $request->title . '.' . $request->image->extension();
    
    $request->image->move(public_path(('images'), $newImageName));
    
    Post::create([
        'title' => $request->input('title'),
        'description' => $request->input('description'),
        'slug' => SlugService::createSlug(Post::class, 'slug', $request->title),
        'image_path' => $newImageName,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id
    ]);

    return redirect('/blog')
    ->with('message', 'Dein Beitrag wurde erstellt.');

}
```

Everything works just fine - exept for the file name. It should have the name of $newImageName but it looks like 'php51F7.tmp'. Also the extension is '.tmp' and not '.png' or '.jpg'.

**Thank you very much for your help!**

*PS: I'm an absolut beginner in Laravel, please be patient.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is issue of extra round bracket**

Replace

```
$request->image->move(public_path(('images'), $newImageName));
```

With

```
$request->image->move(public_path('images'), $newImageName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in your code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg|max:5048'
    ]);
    $newImageName = uniqid() . '-' . $request->title . '.' . $request->image->extension();
    
    #Notice here, move() accepts two parameteres
    $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $newImageName);
    
    Post::create([
        'title' => $request->input('title'),
        'description' => $request->input('description'),
        'slug' => SlugService::createSlug(Post::class, 'slug', $request->title),
        'image_path' => $newImageName,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id
    ]);

    return redirect('/blog')
    ->with('message', 'Dein Beitrag wurde erstellt.');

}
```

Comment: You are amazing! I almost went crazy. Thank you!

Comment: You can refer this blog if you want to store images in storage disk of laravel https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-8-image-upload-tutorial-exampleexample.html